# Vim script function on lua

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I'm rewriting my vim config in lua. I have a useful function for me - it allows me to delete/select/edit numbers, here is its code and key bindings

```
" custom text-object for numerical values
function! Numbers()
    call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
    normal v
    call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')
endfunction
xnoremap in :<C-u>call Numbers()<CR>
onoremap in :normal vin<CR>
```

If I press **cin**, the cursor in the line goes to a number, for example

```
fotn-size: 16px
```

If I press **cin**, I will edit the number ***16***

I tried rewriting the same thing in lua and this is what I got (vimscript inside lua)

```
function Numbers()
  vim.cmd [[
      call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
      normal v
      call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')
    ]]
end

vim.keymap.set({ 'x' }, 'in', ':<C-u>lua Numbers()<CR>', { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set({ 'o' }, 'in', ':normal vin <CR>', { noremap = true })
```

At first I thought it worked fine, but after a little bit of work, I realized it didn't work correctly.

Now, if I press cin, the line

```
fotn-size: 16px
```

I will edit the number 6 and the letter p . Like this 1***6p***x

But in this example.

```
const my_var = 125;
```

when I press **cin** I will not edit the entire number ***125***, but only the last digit ***5***

Please help me, how can I get this function to work correctly in lua?

Comment: I knew that function looked [familiar](https://gist.github.com/romainl/c0a8b57a36aec71a986f1120e1931f20) ;-). Anyway, you are using `ctn` all over your question despite the mappings being `in`. You should clean it up to avoid confusion.

Comment: @romainl I'm sorry, I didn't indicate the key combination correctly, of course it was cin, not ctn. Post has been corrected. The problem is not with the key combination, the problem is that the function does not work correctly, because I did not translate it correctly to lua. It worked correctly in the wim script config.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's some issue when switching between Lua and Vimscript internally. Since you are already using `vim.cmd` you can put all the vimscript in it:

```lua
vim.cmd [[
    function! Numbers()
        call search('\d\([^0-9\.]\|$\)', 'cW')
        normal v
        call search('\(^\|[^0-9\.]\d\)', 'becW')
    endfunction
    xnoremap in :<C-u>call Numbers()<CR>
    onoremap in :normal vin<CR>
]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already done so, everything works correctly now. Ideally, I'd like to rewrite it completely in lua, but I don't know lua at all=))

Comment: you dont have to write all the conf in pure Lua. i have a quite big legacy vimrc and i just `vim.cmd('source ~/.vimrc')` in my `init.lua`.